# How can I create widgets from data structure contents in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

This is what I want to achieve:

[image]

I have created the bellow class to initialize and store object.

```
class WidgetItem {
  SliverList sliverList;
  List<StatefulBuilder> statefulBuilder;
  WidgetItem(this.sliverList, this.statefulBuilder);
}
```

The bellow are used to store list of items:

```
 List<StatefulBuilder> listOfIn = [];
 List<StatefulBuilder> listOfOut = [];
```

To store the objects

```
 List<WidgetItem> listOfItems = [];

  listOfItems.add(new WidgetItem(
    SliverList(
      delegate: SliverChildListDelegate([
        ListTile(
          title: "Header 1",
        ),
      ]),
    ),
    listOfIn));

 listOfItems.add(new WidgetItem(
    SliverList(
      delegate: SliverChildListDelegate([
        ListTile(
          title: "Header 2",
        ),
      ]),
    ),
    listOfIn));
```

I want to show the SliverList and StatefulBuilder widgets as they are stored in`listOfItems`. I have attempted to create the widgets as the bellow code shows.How can I achieve this?

```
return new Scaffold(
       body: CustomScrollView(
             slivers: <Widget>[
             //show all objects from listOfObjects
             list all items from `listOfItems`

      ]
   ))
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you can have a look at [SectionTableView](https://github.com/Realank/flutter_section_table_view) package.